# Что такое "разговорная речь"

Tags: грамотная-речь, терминология, разговорная-речь

Что значит *разговорная речь*? В магазине, в аптеке, в больнице...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Разговорная речь — разновидность современного русского литературного языка, которая используется в неофициальном непосредственном устном общении, её функция — коммуникативная (общение). Разговорная речь спонтанна, т. е. неподготовленная.

Для разговорной речи характерна ситуативность (разговорная речь зависит от речевой ситуации). Такие предложения понятны и естественны в конкретной ситуации общения. Например, речевая ситуация — **разговор в магазине**:

— Маш, ты за кем? (Т. е. за кем заняла очередь?)

— Вон в красной раздергайке. (Просторечие.)

— Эту брать? (Ситуативное неполное предложение.)

— Да, хорошая штука. (Штука — это слово-губка, впитывает в себя много смыслов.)

— Нет, нет, вы мне в синей дайте! (Ситуативное неполное предложение.)

**В аптеке**.

— От кашля есть? Чьё?

— Есть наше и германское.

— А дешевле?

— А от головы?

**В больнице.**

— Ой-ой, милая, куда мне?

— Да вон в раздевалке переоденьтесь, да и в палату.

— В какую?

— Под лестницей налево.

— Всем здравствуйте!

— И вам не хворать...

Вот как-то так: простые разговорные слова, иногда просторечия, неполные простые предложения, междометия, вежливые обращения, описательные  обороты.

Comment: Я позволила себе подправить Ваш ответ (тире, пробелы, описочки, форматирование — без какого-либо изменения Вашего текста). Проверьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Спасибо! Всё очень корректно.